# Can i get screenshot of desktop using vuejs

Tags: vue.js

i am working on tracking app using vue.js. I am a new developer.i wanna know is it possible to track mouse click and capture screenshots even if person is on desktop or any where else on browser

Comment: No, not with any JS framework and for very good reasons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found the solution 
i followed the steps here 
https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/getScreenId/
these steps allowed me the screen sharing on my webpage and then i use html to canvas to get the image of the video tag

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with VueJs specifically. However, you can use HTML5/Canvas/Javascript to take a screenshot, but that's still experimental.

Take a look at this answer: [Using HTML5/Canvas/JavaScript to take in-browser screenshots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-in-browser-screenshots/6678156#6678156)